# Delete photos in the photo folder on mac

Tags: macos, mac, photos

There is a very annoying problem that is bugging me, when I delete a photo in the photo folder on my mac, and I use the photo preview window where I can slide with two fingers on the touchpad to browse the photos, the next photo is showed, but it is **unselected** . If I try to tap one of the arrow buttons, the preview window browses back to the beginning. How to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean with photo preview window? Quicklook?

Comment: Yes, it's the quicklook, where you swipe with two fingers to scroll trough your photos. Try to a delete a photo, the next is showed but it is unselected.